# lotus notes the design element is hidden and cannot be edited

Tags: lotus-notes

Appreciate your help.

I have old lotus notes database. Even having manager access it cannot open in designer.

So, took archive of the database was able to open in designer. Now when I am trying to open code of agents, scripts, formula, etc in current lotus notes version 8.5.3.

It throws error "the design element is hidden and cannot be edited".

Please could you guide on how to view code.

Comment: Please help in this case about "hiding desgin":
https://stackoverflow.com/q/75845895/21491892

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a database with hidden design here. Unless you find the template, that it was created from, there is no way to "unhide" the design as it is only stored "Compiled" in this case.

It it possible to get back "some" of the information using a HEX- Editor on the nsf file, but this will not bring you further than you already are with your backup: You can open in designer but not see any formula (in forms or views)...

When updating a database from a template you can choose to "Hide formulas and LotusScript" and this will result in what you see.

[image: Hide formulas and LotusScript Option]

Some vendors already hide the design of their templates to protect their intellectual property. In that case you will not find an "open" template and cannot get the code back.

Comment: Appreciate Tode,  Yes, previous vendor had not shared the design template and we are now unable to modify any new enhancements requirements. We are totally helpless.