# Lotus Notes DB problem creating documents after DB "Replace Design" and "Hide Formulas and LotusScript" process

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

I developed a Lotus Notes DB and I made a template of it, after I created a new DB using that template and executed a "replace design" and select "Hide formulas and LotusScript" option, the users can not add documents to the created database, to create a document the users must click on a button that has a "@Command([Compose]" action that is on a page inside the main frameset of the BD and when the user click on nothing happens. Im using version 12 of HCL Lotus Notes. I tested with users with Editor and Manager access to the DB.

In the template I changed the form setting to display it in the menu and apply the refresh desing to the created DB, but when the user select it the following error message appears "formula is hidden".  I would like to hide the desing of the DB because I will install the DB in another company and I would like to prevent design modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Do you, anywhere in your code, try to read (part of) the design? We had a similar issue when we tried to read a view’s selection formula. I suppose, but I’m not sure, that form elements are equally off limits…